# Knapsack with max element count in subsets

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

i have an integer array, and i need to find a subset of this array with max 3 elements which is equal to W.

Can i solve this problem using knapsack? or i need to calculate every 1-2-3 element combination of the array?

Thanks already

Comment: @Dukeling it doesn't differ. i just want to see if it matches the rule or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To look for 3 elements** that sum to `W`, this is exactly [the 3SUM problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3sum).

It can be solved in O(n<sup>2</sup>) time by either:

- Inserting each number into a hash table, then, for each combination of two numbers `a` and `b`, checking whether `W-a-b` exists in the hash table.
- Sorting the array, then, for each element `a`, looking right for two elements that sums to `W-a` using 2 iterators from either side.

If the integer range is in the range `[-u, u]`, you can solve your problem using a Fast Fourier transform in O(n + u log u). See the above link for more details on either this or one of the above approaches.

Since your problem is dependent on solving 3SUM, which is a well-known problem, you're very unlikely to find a solution with better running time than the above well-known solutions for 3SUM.

**To look for 1 element:**

You can do a simple linear search (O(n)).

**To look for 2 elements:**

This can be solved by simply checking each combination of 2 elements in O(n<sup>2</sup>) (you needn't do something more complex as the asymptotic running time of 3 elements will result in O(n<sup>2</sup>) total time regardless of how efficient this is).

It can also be solved in O(n) or O(n log n) using methods identical to those described above for 3SUM.

**Overall running time:**

O(n<sup>2</sup>) or O(n + u log u), depending on which method was used to solve the 3SUM part.